# C# интерфейсы и абстрактные классы

Tags: c#, классы, наследование, интерфейс

Доброго!

Есть интерфейс IInterface,

Есть абстрактный класс его реализующий AClass

И есть абстрактный класс

```
AClasses<T>
{
  List<T> Elements;

  void SomeMethod()
  {
    T _el = new T();
    _el.Some();
    Elements.Add(_el);
  }
}
```

Вот в методе SomeMethod() проблема так как это сделать нельзя. T должен наследоваться от IInterface ну или на крайний случай от AClass.

Так вот вопрос. Как заполнить List Elements в абстрактном классе

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, при помощи ограничений на `T`:

```
class AClasses<T> where T : IInterface, new()
{
    ...
```

Это будет работать, если у ваших классов есть пустой конструктор.

Если пустого конструктора нет, то создание экземпляров нужно делать как-нибудь по-другому, например, через фабрику или создающий делегат.

Comment: Тут еще на new ругается

Comment: @АнтонКартушин: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Увидел спасибо большое

Comment: @АнтонКартушин вы галку слева от ответа поставьте, если вас ответ удовлетворил.

Comment: @АнтонКартушин: Пожалуйста, рад, если помогло!

Comment: @Bulson по времени не мог еще, как только так сразу :)